# If $ϕ(h) = L − c_1h − c_2h^2 − c_3h^3 −$ ···, then what combination of ϕ(h) and ϕ(h/2) should give an accurate estimate of L?

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, combinations

a) . If $ϕ(h) = L − c_1h^{1/2} − c_2h^{2/2} − c_3h^{3/2} − ···$, then what combination of $ϕ(h)$ and $ϕ(h/2)$ should give an accurate estimate of L?

b) If $ϕ(h) = L − c_1h − c_2h^2 − c_3h^3 − ···$, then what combination of $ϕ(h)$ and $ϕ(h/2)$ should give an accurate estimate of L?

The solution given in the textbook for b is  $L=2ϕ(h/2)-ϕ(h)$. The solution makes sense if i check it but how do i come to that solution? And do i use the same logic for part a or is there something different with a? (because the power is different.)

Comment: Any thoughts about the answers that have been posted?

Comment: Earth to Tom, come in, please.

Answer (score 0):

If $$\phi(h)=L-c_1h-c_2h^2-c_3h^3-\cdots$$ then $$\phi(h/2)=L-(1/2)c_1h-(1/4)c_2h^2-(1/8)c_3h^3-\cdots$$ so we see the term in $h$ will cancel if we compute $$2\phi(h/2)-\phi(h)=L+(1/2)c_2h^2+(3/4)c_3h^3+\cdots$$ and give us that $L$ is estimated by $2\phi(h/2)-\phi(h)$ with error on the order of $h^2$.

Now see what you can do with (a).

Answer (score 0):

More generally,
suppose
$f(h)
=L-ch^a-dh^b+o(h^b)
$
where
$0 < a < b$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
uf(h)+vf(h/2)
&=u(L-ch^a-dh^b+o(h^b))+v(L-c(h/2)^a-d(h/2)^b+o(h^b))\\
&=(u+v)L-ch^a(u+v/2^a)-dh^b(u+v/2^b)+o(h^b)\\
\end{array}
$

To have this
as close to $L$ as possible,
thie requires
$u+v = 1$
and
$u+v/2^a = 0$.

From this,
$v = 1-u$
so
$0
= u+(1-u)/2^a
=u(1-1/2^a)+1/2^a
$
or
$u(2^a-1) = -1
$
or
$u 
= \dfrac1{1-2^a}
= -\dfrac1{2^a-1}
$
and
$v
= 1-u
=1+\dfrac1{2^a-1}
=\dfrac{2^a}{2^a-1}
$.

The error is now

$\begin{array}\\
dh^b(u+v/2^b)
&=dh^b(-\dfrac1{2^a-1}+\dfrac{2^a}{2^a-1}/2^b)\\
&=dh^b(\dfrac{2^{a-b}-1}{2^a-1})\\
\end{array}
$

For the second case.
when $a = 1$,
$u 
= \dfrac1{1-2^1}
=-1
$
and
$v = 1-u
=2$
so we want
$-f(h)+2f(h/2)
$.

For the first case.
when $a = 1/2$,
$u 
= \dfrac1{1-2^{1/2}}
= -\dfrac1{2^{1/2}-1}
= -\dfrac1{2^{1/2}-1}\dfrac{2^{1/2}+1}{2^{1/2}+1}
= -(2^{1/2}+1)
$
and
$v = 1-u
=2+2^{1/2}
$
so we want
$(2+2^{1/2})f(h/2)-(2^{1/2}+1)f(h)
$.